# Loading data from Geoserver in Leaflet js

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

I am trying to load data from Geoserver into my website using Leaflet but I get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" with my Url link to my GeoJSON link.

I'm confused about proxy and CORS but I expect this could be the answer but I am hoping for an easier solution. If anyone is able to help me to solve this problem I will be very grateful.

This is the code I am trying to run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="markers" type="images/marker-icon" href="images/marker-icon.png" />

    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'></script>

 </head>
 <body>

   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script>

    var mymap = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:true, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
        }).fitBounds([[51.0269253989,-1.34762355597],[51.1990603009,-0.951310026203]]);

    L.esri.basemapLayer('Imagery').addTo(mymap);

    //loads the geojson layer
    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();

    function loadGeoJson(data) { 
        geojson.addGeoJSON(data); 
    } 
        var geoJsonUrl = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/RSAC/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=RSAC:results_clipped_with_growth_small&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson";

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: geoJsonUrl + '&callback=?', 
            dataType: 'json',
            jsonpCallback: 'loadGeoJson',
            success: loadGeoJson,   
    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the URL work in the browser?

Comment: Yes, the URL does work in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'></script>
```

You included jQuery twice, version 1.5 (very old and outdated) after 1.11.0. Simply remove the second jQuery.

In your Javascript jQuery fetches data in JSONP format. However, the Geoserver URL with `outputFormat=application/json` will send JSON (not JSONP).

To disable the jQuery's JSONP checks you'll have to provide the parameter `jsonp: false` here:

> Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes `jsonp: false` in its request options. [(source)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: geoJsonUrl, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: loadGeoJson,
    jsonp: false 
});
```

I tested this with a random public Geoserver instance and had no issues with CORS, but your mileage may vary.